# Fullcalendar for multiple type of schedules

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I'm using full calendar and I need to fetch events where schedules can be weekly,daily or monthly type or they can have multiple types.
 I will be getting all the schedules in the 'schedule' given below..please help me out of this. Thanks in advance.

```
$scope.getResidentInterventions = function () {
            blockUI.start();
            var residentList = [];
            var getResidentInt_URL = $scope.constants.API.GET_RESIDENT_1 + $scope.selectedResidentID + $scope.constants.API.GET_RESIDENT_2
                + $scope.selectedFacilityID
                + $scope.constants.API.GET_RESIDENT_INTERVENTION

            residentService.get(getResidentInt_URL).then(
                function (response) {
                    // if (response.data) {
                    $scope.residentList = [];
                    $scope.residentIntList = response.data;
                    console.log("$scope.residentIntList", $scope.residentIntList);
                    //$scope.schedules = [];
                    $scope.residentIntList.forEach(function (problem) {
                        problem.rcp_goals.forEach(function (goal) {
                            goal.rcp_interventions.forEach(function (intervention) {
                                if (intervention.rcp_interventionfrequency != null) {
                                    intervention.rcp_interventionfrequency.schedules.forEach(function (schedule) {
                                        console.log(schedule);
                                        //console.log(schedule.Schedule);
                                        //console.log("$scope.schedules", $scope.schedules);
                                        for (var weekKey in weekList) {
                                            //for (var key in $scope.schedules) F{
                                            var testSchedule = {};
                                            if (weekKey == schedule.Schedule) {
                                                testSchedule = {
                                                    //title: "Test",
                                                    // start: "2017-04-21T00:00:00.000Z", end: "2017-04-22T00:00:00.000Z",
                                                    start: "10:00", end: "2:00",
                                                    dow: [parseInt(weekList[weekKey])]
                                                };
                                                $scope.schedules.push(testSchedule);                     
                                                $scope.RefreshCalenderEvents($scope.schedules);
                                                break;
                                            }                             
                                      });
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: here is the weeklist   var weekList = {
                "Sun": "0",
                "Mon": "1",
                "Tue": "2",
                "Wed": "3",
                "Thurs": "4",
                "Fri": "5",
                "Sat": "6"
            };

Comment: FrequencyID
:
166
Schedule
:
"09:00 AM"
ScheduleID
:
109
ScheduleTypeID
:
1

Comment: there's a lot of existing code here, but your question is too vague. Please explain what your current code does vs what you want to do, how you've attempted to implement your requirement so far, and where it fails. Also if you have extra info please edit it into the question rather than putting in the comments.